# How to make cdc skip the point that it is stuck at?

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have an issue where the transnational log has grown to its max size.
Running fn_dblog I noticed that its complaining that a drop was done. It looks like cdc is stuck there. The description column in fn_dblog displays DROPOBJ;0X01.......

Also, the cdc capture job gives the following error message "...Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, String or binary data would be truncated. For more information, query the sys.dm_cdc_errors dynamic management view."

**So this is what happened that could have caused this...**

- I created a script that (1) disabled triggers (2) created table (3) created cdc table. I ran this and it was successful.
- I made a mistake with the table name, so I dropped the table. I did this without disabling the cdc for this table.
- I had then edited the script (mentioned in point 1) by correcting the table name and ran it again, yes it complained about the cdc already exiting.

I did not do anything else at this point.

Can someone please advise on a solution to maybe allow cdc to bypass where it is stuck at.

I'm new to databases please bare with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the cdc cleanup job.
It should have a name similar to this.

```
[cdc.Replication_cleanup]
```